# How to store user information in database in Angular 2?

Tags: sql, database

i want to store user information in database using sql server in Angular 2, How can is it possible?

Comment: Angular2+ is a client-side framework and you can't interact with the database with it. You should have a server-side app to handle database interactions like nodejs, Django, ...

Comment: You can connect Angular to PHP or any other backend using HttpClient check it out here: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is a front-end framework and In order to store user information, you should probably have a back-end connected to your app (NodeJS or Java),  or else, you can use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/).

If you have a back-end, for an example, say java, You can connect your Java Back-end with SQL Server and store passwords there.

But as I understand, what you need to implement is a small authentication system for your app. In this case, Firebase is the easiest solution. You can do this with the help of [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). Follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-2-firebase-authentication-7593c565fa53).